# Topology Editing using ArcView (now called Basic) license level of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, database, topology, basic-license-level

I am building a geodatabase from data collected on a GPS handheld in the field.

The GPS device collects decently accurate information but I need to make sure all the polygons, lines, and points are aligning correctly.

I currently have the an Arcview license and don't believe I can create my own topology.

Is there any work around or extension that I can download, instead of upgrading my ArcGIS license to create and edit the topology in this way?

Comment: QGIS with the Topology Checker Plugin http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html would be an alternative

Answer (score 1):

To work with topology using a Basic (formerly called ArcView) level license you can use [map topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01mm0000000r000000) on your file geodatabase:

> A map topology creates topological relationships between the parts of
>   features that are coincident, which allows you to simultaneously edit
>   features that share geometry. You can create a map topology for point,
>   line, or polygon layers from shapefiles or geodatabase feature
>   classes. The features can be in one or more layers and have different
>   layer types.
>
> It is easy to create a map topology. You simply choose the layers to
>   participate and set the cluster tolerance. In addition, if you click
>   the Topology Edit tool without having an active topology, you are
>   prompted to set up the topology.

Standard/Advanced level licensing is only required when wanting to store topological relationships in your geodatabase.  Your requirement seems to be only for topology editing rather than storage.